# How can you mutate (empty strings) as NA in only one variable?

Tags: r, missing-data

How can you transform empty strings to NA in a variable?

So the context is I have 4 datasets that are combined (4 surveys). In one of those datasets and in one variable in particular, the "NA" data are classified as (empty strings). How do I modify/transform/mutate those (empty strings) as `NA` without affecting the rest of the dataset?

What I saw that I think could work is this:

`dat <- dat %>% mutate_all(na_if, "")`

The problem is obviously that this selects all the data.

What worked was

```
nav <- c('', ' ')
ECEMD <- transform(ECEMD, CHILDREN_DIM = replace (CHILDREN_DIM, CHILDREN_DIM %in% nav, NA))
```

Comment: Please read the info at the top of the [tag:r] tag and, in particular, provide a complete  reproducible example that others can run.  To do that include all inputs using `dput`.

Comment: Just do `dat <- dat %>% mutate(your_variable = if_else(your_variable == "", NA_character_, your_variable))`.  I'm assuming here that by `"NA"` you meant the `NA` value, rather than a string with the letters `"N"` and `"A"`.  **Note:** Since the `NA` value is logical by default, you need to use `NA_character_` (or `as.character(NA)`) to make the `NA`s compatible with the strings in your column.

Comment: @Greg 
I tried what you said. 

ECEMD %>%
  mutate(CHILDREN_DIM = if_else(CHILDREN_DIM =="", NA_character_, CHILDREN_DIM))

but when I look at the frequencies, (Empty string) didn't mutate in <NA>

Comment: @FALA What exactly do you mean by _"(Empty string)"_?  Do you mean the string value `""`, or do you mean a "blank cell"?  This would be easier to answer if you pasted the output from `dput(ECEMD)`.

Comment: @Greg the data has more than 200k participants with over 250 questions, so it just made a gigantic mess...  Is there another way?

Comment: @FALA Oops, didn't realize how big it was.  Try `dput(head(ECEMD, 20))` for the top 20 rows.

Comment: @FALA Thanks for the output! But please edit your question to include this output, rather than posting it in the comments.

Comment: @Greg ok just did that

Comment: @FALA  Great!  Did you miss anything from the bottom, by any chance?  Also, I'd suggest putting the output within code fences (```) rather than backticks (`).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming sort of this data.

```
dat
#    want_na non_na
# 1        A      A
# 2        B      B
# 3                
# 4        D      D
# 5                
# 6        F      F
# 7                
# 8        H      H
# 9        I      I
# 10       J      J
```

Then define a vector containing all values you want to  with `NA`, e.g.

```
nav <- c('', ' ')
```

and `replace` them in a defined variable, `"want_na"` in this example.

```
dat <- transform(dat, want_na=replace(want_na, want_na %in% nav, NA))
dat
#    want_na non_na
# 1        A      A
# 2        B      B
# 3     <NA>       
# 4        D      D
# 5     <NA>       
# 6        F      F
# 7     <NA>       
# 8        H      H
# 9        I      I
# 10       J      J
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(want_na = c("A", "B", "", "D", "", "F", "", "H", 
"I", "J"), non_na = c("A", "B", "", "D", "", "F", "", "H", "I", 
"J")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: It says object 'want_na' not found

`nav <- c('', ' ')
ECEMD <- transform(ECEMD, want_na = replace (want_na, want_na %in% nav, NA))`

Comment: @FALA You need to use the respective variable name in your dataset instead of `want_na`.

Comment: This worked! Thanks alot

Comment: You're welcome @FALA

Comment: BTW, please consider to [mark an answer accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) if it helped you. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

What worked was

```
nav <- c('', ' ')
ECEMD <- transform(ECEMD, CHILDREN_DIM = replace (CHILDREN_DIM, CHILDREN_DIM %in% nav, NA))
```